# Utillize string filename from form1 to form 2

Tags: c#, xml

In form 1 I have open an xml file.  Now I want to able to use the string filename in Form2 so I am able to do extra feature and/or use what inside the file.

```
       Form1

               DialogResult result;
               string filename;

            private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
              {
                 fileChooser.Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
                 fileChooser.CheckFileExists = false;
                 result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
                filename = fileChooser.FileName;
                }
             }


         Form2
    namespace PreviewForm
  {
     public partial class Preview : Form
    {
        int ind1 = 1;

        public Preview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Preview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //I want to able to do something like this

        //XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        //xDoc.Load(filename);

        //foreach(XmlNode xNode in xdoc.SelectNode(People/People))
        //{
        //    Label lable1 = new Label(); 
        //    label1.Text = xNode.SelectingSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
        //    label1.Name = "label_" + ind1;
        //    label1.Location = new Point(code);
        //    ind1++;
        //    this.Controls.Add(label1);


    }

   }
}
```

So I want to able to use the string filename in form1 to form2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a private field instance and add it to the constructor

```
 namespace PreviewForm
  {
    private  string _filename = string.Empty;
     public partial class Preview : Form
    {
        int ind1 = 1;

        public Preview(string filename)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
          _filename = filename;  
    }
```

to use the string filename in Form2

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
              {
                 fileChooser.Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
                 fileChooser.CheckFileExists = false;
                 result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
                filename = fileChooser.FileName;
                //for example  here  
                 PreviewForm form2=new PreviewForm(filepath);
                 form2.ShowDialog(this); 
                }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** You can send the `FilePath` from `Form1` to the `Form2` using  `constructor` as below:

```
Form2 form2=new Fomr2(filepath);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

and create a string parameter constructor in Form2 as below:

```
      string filepath;

      public Preview(string filepath)
      { 
      InitializeComponent();
      this.filepath=filepath;
      }
```

**Solution 2:** Make the filepath variable as `public` `static` in `Form1` so that it can be accessible using its classname.

Try This:

```
       public static string filepath;
       private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
          {
             fileChooser.Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
             fileChooser.CheckFileExists = false;
             result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
             filename = fileChooser.FileName;
             Form2 form2=new Fomr2(filepath);
             form2.ShowDialog();
            }
         }
```

From Form2 :

You can access from as below:

```
String filepath = Form1.filepath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some have already posted working examples, but I'd like to give you a general overview of what can be done when you need to pass data from a class to another one.

I'm presenting you with 3 basic ways to pass your data from the first class (the sender class) to the second (the receiver class):

1. Constructor Injection. This is what most people have described here, and it basically mean to have a "special" constructor on your receiver class that will be called from the sender class to pass the necessary data as a parameter when the receiver class object is instantiated. The data can then be saved to a local member on the receiver class.
2. Setter Injection. In this case, you define a public property on the receiver class that you call from the sender class, but after the receiver has been instantiated. As with the constructor injection, you can save the data to a local member on the receiver.
3. Method Injection. In this case, you define a method on the receiver class that will have a parameter defined to receive the data. here you can either decide to store the data to a member of the receiver, but you could also decide to use the data directly in the method body and discard it when done.

This is by no mean an exhaustive list of how you can pass data between classes, but it will give you a good starting point.

Cheers